# Having some issues trying to unmount the home partition and resize/split it

Tags: ubuntu, partitioning, gparted, umount

So i'm new to linux and I set up my drive poorly....basically too small of a root partition and too large of a home partition and I want to have a Mysql and Nginx partition as well for that data.

I've enabled the root login on the box and logged in a root and lsof and fuser are both reporting no open files for the /home partition but gParted is still listing is as locked.

I'm not sure where to go... I want to shrink down the home partition and add a mySQL data and Nginx data partition so as to give a bit more flexibility.....

I get no response back from

```
sudo lsof /home
```

and from

```
fuser -mv /home
```

I get

```
                     USER        PID ACCESS COMMAND

 /home:               root     kernel mount /home
```

umount says

```
umount: /home: target is busy.
```

But I can't see how it is busy......

### Thanks

Comment: You need to do that from a live session. You can't manage partitions that are in use.

Comment: And you should know how to do what you want and the risks involved. A reinstallation with the proper partitioning is safer and in some cases even faster than shrinking/moving/resizing.

Comment: the point is is should not be in use I understand the risks and you should be able to resize a partition/unmount one that is not in use

Comment: Exactly, when *not* in use... The problem is no matter how you login, root or not (BTW, you shouldn't use root, that's NOT how Debian/Ubuntu works), you CAN'T unmount /home or / for that matter. So, again, LIVE SESSION.

Comment: @changanauto - why cant you unmount home if you have a live session?

Comment: when you were doing this, were you logged in to the GUI ? That could cause files to be open.

Comment: You can't unmount a partition in use when you use you installed system, the one where you want to manage partitions, supposedly... That why I said and repeated LIVE SESSION. In a live session you CAN manage the partitions of your installed system because they AREN'T in use, they aren't mounted by default. This is Linux 101 since... ever.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so for anyone interested....

1. Enable the root user temporarily
2. Check for open files LSOF /mountpoint check for processes using on
3. Check for any shares on the volume using showmount command
4. Make sure you are not in any directory in the mounted volume
5. Launch gParted and resize and unmount as needed
6. Relaunch Ubuntu and disable the root account for access.

Seemed to work grandly..and before you do this back up your home and any other data you don't want to lose..